# ConTeXt : inline code highlighting with t-vim

Tags: context, code, t-vim

I am trying to insert code in a ConTeXt document, so I tryed to use the vimtyping module. It works well for text blocks, but not for inline text, since it makes a new line. Here is my MWE:

```
\setuppapersize[A5][A5]
\usemodule[vim]
\definevimtyping[python][
  syntax=python,
  strip=yes,
  tab=4,
  margin=2em,
  before={\blank[samepage,line]},
  after={\blank[line]},
]

\starttext
The block works
\startpython
  def function(foo):  # test
      a = foo
      return(foo**a)
\stoppython
But the inline writing of \inlinepython{def function} makes new lines.
\stoptext
```

Is there an option I need to activate to use this module inline macro ?

Comment: Leave out the `before` and `after` options.

Comment: Can you make a detailed answer so I can validate it as ok ? It would be better than if it is I who answers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are `spacebefore` and `spaceafter` keys that you should use to set up spaces.

This is not a bug, but is due to misconfigured defaults. The `before` and `after` values are used only when you use `\start<vim-typing>` ... `\stop<vim-typing>`; when you use `\inline<vim-typing>`, `left` and `right` keys get used.

But, in `t-filter`, I had defined:

```
\c!left=\externalfilterparameter\c!before,
\c!right=\externalfilterparameter\c!after,
```

So, the default values of `left` and `right` were same as that of `before` and `after`. So, to avoid the wrong behaviour, add:

```
\definevimtyping[python]
   [
     ...,
     left=,
     right=,
   ]
```

so that `left` and `right` keys are set to be empty.

NOTE: Actually, I had fixed this bug [a while back](https://github.com/adityam/filter/commit/075dabcba2d6ed656e271efd0632611ba912e96e), but modules.contextgarden.net is down; so I haven't been able to update the module in the distribution.